# Acceder al resultado de un método flutter

Tags: flutter

Buen día me encuentro haciendo una app de ventas en flutter actualmente tengo problemas para acceder a un resultado que obtengo de un metodo que cree en la base de datos, al apretar cada producto hace una suma y guarda el resultado pero actualmente solo lo puedo ver en consola con un print, pero no he podido acceder al metodo, lo que quiero es que lo que regresa getDetalleId(), mostrarlo en un text.

```
onTap: () async {
                      print('El id del ticket es: ${ticket_id}');
                      double cantidad = 1;
                      double subtotal = cantidad * product.precioProd;
                      double iva = subtotal * (product.porcIva / 100);
                      double ieps = subtotal * (product.porcIeps / 100);
                      double total = subtotal + iva + ieps;
                      //si llegase a haber descuentos me los envia el servidor y hago la operacion aquí y se agrega en el insert en vez de 0
                      final resp = await DBXicaras.db.newDetalle(
                          new DetalleModel(
                              clvProd: product.claveProd,
                              precio: product.precioProd,
                              idTicket: ticket_id,
                              cantidad: 1,
                              tipoVenta: 1,
                              subtotal: subtotal,
                              prodIva: iva,
                              prodIeps: ieps,
                              total: total,
                              unidad: product.unidad,
                              porcDesc: 0,
                              descProd: 0));

                      print('detalle correcto: $resp');
                      final detaLl =
                          await DBXicaras.db.getDetalleId(ticket_id);
                      print('RESPUESTA A CONSULTAS DE DETALLES $detaLl');
                    },
```

respuesta en consola: I/flutter (30362): RESPUESTA A CONSULTAS DE DETALLES 242.94400000000005

metodo en db:

getDetalleId(int id) async {

```
final db = await database;
var res = await db.rawQuery('''
  SELECT SUM(total) AS tgeneral FROM detalle WHERE id_ticket = '$id'     
''');

var dbitem = res.first;


return dbitem['tgeneral'];
```

}

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: te falta el setState para refrescar el contenido del widget

Comment: Pero como accedo al contenido que necesito?

Answer (score 0):

Hola te dejo este fragmento de código que hice en base a lo que muestras, si te das cuenta utilizas un **StateFulWidget** para poder crear una variable global.

Esta variable no la declaras final, para poder siempre actualizarla con el dato que viene de tu base de datos, recuerda que la llamada a base de datos va dentro de **setState()**.

Después de eso solo tienes que poner el valor de la variable **detaLl** el cualquier Widget donde desees mostrarlo, acá yo muestro ese valor en un **Text()**

Espero te sirva. Saludos

```
class FlutterExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FlutterExampleState createState() => _FlutterExampleState();
}

class _FlutterExampleState extends State<FlutterExample> {
  String detaLl;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text('Aca puedes mostrar el valor de $detaLl'),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() async {
              detaLl = await DBXicaras.db.getDetalleId(ticket_id);
                      print('RESPUESTA A CONSULTAS DE DETALLES $detaLl');
            });
          },
          child: Text('Presioname'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Entiendo que faltaria tambien darle un valor vacio al string o hacer un chequeo de que mostrar cuando su valor es "null" ya que al principio no tiene un valor y daria un error al mostrar la pantalla.

Comment: Si en el ejemplo de arriba lo que va a hacer es que cuando no tenga valor en el Text te va a salir `"Aca puedes mostrar el valor de null"`, por lo que vale la pena declararlo algo mas como `String detaLl = '';`